# Company recreates dead people as androids using data from social networks

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

Please help identify the name of a movie I saw partially, where there's a company that specializes in collecting information about someone (from social networks), and uploads that data into an android/robot. So, a women pays them to "recreate" her deceased husband. Well, in the end she doesn't want the robot any more ...

Comment: Is it from hollywood? Do you remember when you saw it?

Comment: This kind of plot sounds less and less like a (science) fiction... :-/

Comment: I don't think this is Hollywood-made, there were no famous actors. I saw it this year in a friend's house.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Episode 1 of Series 2 of [Black Mirror](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2290780/):

> Martha (Hayley Atwell) and Ash (Domhnall Gleeson) are a young couple
>   who move to a remote house in the countryside. Ash is a social media
>   addict and compulsively checks his phone for updates on his social
>   network pages. The day after moving into the house, Ash is killed
>   returning the hire van. At the funeral, Martha's friend Sarah (Sinead
>   Matthews) tells her about a new online service that lets people stay
>   in touch with the deceased. By using all of his past online
>   communications and social media profiles, a new "Ash" can be created
>   virtually. Martha rejects the idea outright, but Sarah signs Martha up
>   to the service anyway, without telling her. When Martha is sent an
>   e-mail supposedly from Ash, she furiously confronts Sarah, who urges
>   her to at least give the service a try before dismissing it.
>
> Over the following days, Martha is overwhelmed by grief, and soon
>   discovers that she is pregnant. Becoming emotionally unstable, she
>   responds to the artificial Ash's e-mail. She starts to communicate
>   with him through instant messaging, and informs him of the pregnancy.
>   She then uploads videos and photos of Ash to the service's database,
>   and the service duplicates Ash's voice to talk to Martha over the
>   phone. Martha allows herself to believe that she is talking to her
>   dead partner, and over the following weeks she talks to the artificial
>   Ash almost non-stop, keeping him updated regarding the pregnancy.
>   After Martha accidentally damages her phone and has a panic attack
>   when she temporarily loses contact with the service, the artificial
>   Ash tells her about the service's next stage, which is still in its
>   experimental phase: a body made of synthetic flesh that the program
>   can be uploaded onto.
>
> Martha buys a blank, synthetic body from the service, and following
>   the artificial Ash's instructions she allows the body to take on Ash's
>   physical characteristics. The end result is a clone that looks almost
>   exactly like Ash, only missing minor characteristics such as his
>   facial hair and a mole on his neck. From the moment the clone is
>   activated, Martha is uncomfortable and struggles to accept its
>   existence. Despite the clone satisfying her sexually, she quickly
>   becomes frustrated by it constantly doing what she says without
>   question, its lack of emotion (only expressing emotions when she tells
>   it to do so), and the absence of certain habits and personality traits
>   which the real Ash had but the service did not have information on.
>   After an argument, Martha decides she can no longer tolerate the Ash
>   clone, taking it to the edge of a tall cliff and ordering it to jump
>   off. The clone agrees to do so, but Martha grows even angrier, saying
>   that the real Ash would not have willingly jumped. The clone responds
>   by begging for its own life, causing Martha to realise that she can't
>   bring herself to get rid of it.
>
> The scene cuts to several years later, and Martha is shown to have
>   raised her daughter (Indira Ainger) in the country house, keeping the
>   Ash clone locked in the attic. She allows her daughter (who is never
>   named) to see the clone on weekends, but the daughter convinces Martha
>   to allow her into the attic on her birthday to give it a piece of
>   birthday cake. While her daughter is in the attic with the clone,
>   Martha waits at the bottom of the attic steps, close to tears.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Black_Mirror_episodes#Series_2

Comment: Wow - The Stepford Wives meets Facebook!